# turn java vectors into javascript objects

Tags: java, javascript, browser, local-storage, storage

I have a set of vectors (1 for IDs one for names) I want to create an object in javascript for each element of a vector (containing 1 ID 1 name) and I want to store that in local storage. what would be the syntax for me to dynamically create these objects with what I'm guessing would be a for loop?

Comment: How is that connected to Java?

Comment: I intend to use a java method to put the vectors into javascript vars

Comment: Have you looked at any JSON library (like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson))?

Comment: for some reason it won't work for me. the localStorage stuff works fine but JSON isn't responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by just passing strings. A set of strings for each column works fine.